# How to register push notification on PubNub with Firebase FCM token in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, pubnub

I'm working on an iOS Swift project in which I have done WebRTC Video call and Chat using PubNub signaling server. Also I have implemented the Firebase push notification. And this push notification is working fine. But when I got an incoming video call or chat, the backend team is sending notification via Pubnub. So I checked the Pubnub document for registering the device with FCM token in the Pubnub. But I found two methods for registering, first one is

```
public func modifyPushChannelRegistrations(
    byRemoving removals: [String],
    thenAdding additions: [String],
    for deviceToken: Data,
    of pushType: PushRouter.PushType = .apns,
    with networkConfiguration: NetworkConfiguration? = nil,
    respondOn queue: DispatchQueue = .main,
    completion: ((Result<ModifiedPushChannelsPayloadResponse, Error>) -> Void)?) {
         
 }
```

and the second one is

```
public func modifyAPNSDevicesOnChannels(
    byRemoving removals: [String],
    thenAdding additions: [String],
    device token: Data,
    on topic: String,
    environment: PushRouter.Environment = .development,
    with networkConfiguration: NetworkConfiguration? = nil,
    respondOn queue: DispatchQueue = .main,
    completion: ((Result<ModifiedPushChannelsPayloadResponse, Error>) -> Void)?) {

}
```

And which one I should use? Also I want to use FCM push notification. So I need to pass the FCM token on the parameter 'device token' and which is expecting 'Data' type. I used the first method with Pushtype as .apns and I pass the device  token as FCM token(Convert  the string FCM token to Data type) and I got failure response and says Invalid Push token. Then I changed the Pushtype as .gcm and then I got success response but when I test on the Pubnub debug console, I'm not receiving any callback in this method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                  willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                  withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
                  @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

}
```

I don't know whether I'm trying the correct method or not. If anyone of you register the push notification on Pubnub with FCM token please help me back.

Here is my code,

```
var deviceToken = String()
var dataToken = Data()
if let notificationToken = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "FCMToken") as? String {  
   deviceToken = notificationToken
   dataToken = Data(deviceToken.utf8) //Converting String device token to Data
}

var channelName = String()
self.pubnub.modifyPushChannelRegistrations(byRemoving: [], thenAdding: [callChannel, chatChannel], for: dataToken, of: .gcm) {
   result in
   switch result {
      case let .success(response):
         print("Successful Push Modification Response: \(response)")

      case let .failure(error):
         print("Failed Push List Response: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift Push Code**
For Swift, be sure you register your `pushType` using `.apns2`

**Android Push Code**
For FCM push notifications, there are two types you can send/receive: *data* and *notification*. The *notification* type will display automatically on your device when in the background. The *data* type needs to be explicitly handled and displayed.

See the Pubnub docs that mention this and there is a link to the FCM docs with all the details:
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/resources/mobile-push-troubleshooting#check-fcm-payload

Also on the PubNub docs is some sample code. Here is a snippet of the callback method that handles both Data and Notification types with some explanation of both:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
/*
STEP 5: receive push notifications from FCM
*/
  /*
    There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages.
    Data messages are handled here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in
    the foreground or background. Data messages are the type traditionally
    used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in
    onMessageReceived when the app is in the foreground. When the app is in
    the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    When the user taps on the notification they're returned to the app. Messages
    containing both notification and data payloads are treated as notification
    messages. The Firebase console always sends notification messages.
    For more refer to: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    */
}
```

This code snippet comes from the PubNub docs that include all the other steps.
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/messages/push/send#android-devices

Hope that helps you get resolution. If not, please contact [PubNub support](https://support.pubnub.com) with all your details/errors and include a link to this SO post.

Comment: Hi @Craig Conover Ok if I choose push type as .apns, do I need to pass the deviceToken or FCM token in the parameter device token?

Comment: Because I tried as .apns and when I passed the fcm token (which is converted from String to Data), it response failure.

Comment: .apns = certs, .apns2 = tokens, .gcm = fcm

Comment: If you continue to have issue, I encourage you to contact [PN Support}(https://support.pubnub.com) with all these details and paste link to this SO.

Comment: @Hilaj - to answer you question directly, register Android devices using `.fcm` or `.gcm` if fcm is not an option. They both resolve to the same type on our backend (FCM).

Answer (score 0):

Stick to the second option of using Pushtype as .gcm then once you receive your token try and handle the success message back to PubNub as an object. Otherwise your code looks fine.